# Как написать компаратор для сортировки?

Tags: javascript, сортировка, javascript-faq

Как отсортировать числовой массив?
Как отсортировать массив объектов по нескольким полям?

Comment: Сам спросил - сам сразу же ответил.
Почаще бы так ;)

А зачем, если не секрет? Чисто в образовательных целях?

Comment: @0xFFh, встретил очередной огород из условных операторов и решил написать :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а чем метка [tag:сортировка] не угодила?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Стандартная сортировка

Функция `sort` по умолчанию приводит элементы массива к строкам, а затем сортирует.

```
[1,-8,90,32,0,0,5,92,900].sort()
// [-8, 0, 0, 1, 32, 5, 90, 900, 92]
```

Если массив состоит из чисел, то такое поведение является нежелательным.

## Использование компаратора

Функция `sort` может принимать аргумент - компаратор.

Компаратор - это функция, которая принимает 2 аргумента и возвращает отрицательное число, если первый меньше, положительное, если второй меньше и 0, если они равны.

Для чисел достаточно распространено использование вычитания в качестве компаратора:

```
[1,-8,90,32,0,0,5,92,900].sort(function(a, b) {
  return a-b;
})
// [-8, 0, 0, 1, 5, 32, 90, 92, 900]
```

Вообще, следует с осторожностью относиться к этой конструкции из-за возможного переполнения, но в большинстве случаев она работает.

## Компаратор на основе сравнения

Можно вспомнить, что во многих языках true приводится к 1, а false - к 0.

Воспользуемся этой возможностью. Только одно из условий `a<b` и `b<a` истинно, поэтому разность `(b<a) - (a<b)` замечательно подходит на роль компаратора:

```
[1,-8,90,32,0,0,5,92,900].sort(function(a, b) {
  return (b<a) - (a<b);
})
// [-8, 0, 0, 1, 5, 32, 90, 92, 900]
```

Какие тут плюсы? Помимо невозможности переполнения, такое сравнение можно использовать не только с числами. Например, строки вычитать мы не можем, а сравнивать можем.

Для сортировки по убыванию надо просто поменять сравнения местами:

```
[1,-8,90,32,0,0,5,92,900].sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a<b) - (b<a);
})
// [900, 92, 90, 32, 5, 1, 0, 0, -8]
```

## Сортировка по нескольким полям

При сравнении по нескольким полям требуется, чтобы следующее поле сравнивалось только когда предыдущие равны. Это значит, что часть компаратора, выполняющая сравнение тех полей при вычислении даёт 0.

Таким образом, для объединения сравнений полей замечательно подходит оператор `||`, возвращающий первое истинное (в нашем случае ненулевое) значение, либо самое последнее (в нашем случае 0), если все ложны. Таким способом можно объединить любое количество полей.

Отсортируем массив по имени и id:

```
[{name:"John", id:7}, {name:"John",id:4}, {name:"Adam",id:3}, {name:"Adam",id:30}, {name:"Rose",id:1}].sort(function(a, b) {
  return (b.name<a.name) - (a.name<b.name) || (b.id<a.id) - (a.id<b.id);
})
// [{"name":"Adam","id":3},{"name":"Adam","id":30},{"name":"John","id":4},{"name":"John","id":7},{"name":"Rose","id":1}]
```

Comment: Почему выражение `a-b` в теле функции может привести к переполнению? Переполнению стека?

Comment: @Leonid, нет, числовому переполнению. В js [условно не может](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764250/178988).

Comment: Мои эксперименты показали, что все равно получится либо Infinity, либо -Infinity. А это в любом случае либо отрицательное, либо положительное число.

Comment: @Leonid, ещё может получиться NaN, но вроде бы браузер его считает за равенство.

Comment: В предлагаемом способе сортировки по нескольким полям, один момент не совсем ясен: при `||`-чейнинге выражений компаратора, разве мы не получим сортировку "по одному первому полю которое различается", вместо ожидаемой "по нескольким полям"? То есть, сортировка по нескольким полям ведь предполагает то что _все_ из этих нескольких (участвующих в сортировке) полей учитываются, а тут этого не происходит фактически... или я не догоняю?))

Comment: @yar85, не догоняете. Когда будет вычислен второй член оператора "||"? Тогда и только тогда, когда первый был false. В каком случае первый член будет false? Если он будет равен нулю. В каком случае он будет равен нулю? В том, если и "<" вернёт false, и ">", как следствие, тоже. Когда это возможно? Тогда, когда имена равны. Вот тогда-то мы и переходим к сортировке по id. А это и есть сортировка по нескольким полям во всей красе

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, пожалуйста, предложите улучшающую правку в мой ответ на этот вопрос (там есть готовый сниппет), показывающую правильное применение ||-чейнинга.

Comment: @yar85, не для того я уходил с ruSO, чтобы правки вносить хД Так причём тут ваш ответ? Комментарий-то вы оставили к ответу Квертия. И я объясняю, что его применение "||" соответствует описанной идее. В вашем ответе и идея совсем другая: вы не сортируете "по нескольким полям" (в классическом понимании сего термина), вы "присваиваете" объекту новое свойство, вес, динамически рассчитаный по определённым критериям, и потом уже сортируете по этому новому свойству

Comment: Мой ответ при том, что в нем есть готовый кодсниппет (практически показывающий то же самое, что я написал в комментарии), то есть не потребуется больших усилий чтобы продемонстрировать ошибку. С замечанием о принципе подхода в моем ответе - согласен, а вот насчет классического определения термина, не совсем понятно... Можете привести ссылку на источник того определения, которое имеете в виду?

Comment: @yar85, пингуйте человека, которому адресуете вопрос, иначе оный его может не увидеть :) Причём тут ошибка? Я же не говорю, что ваш код не работает. Он работает, но преследует другую идею. А по поводу "классического" понимания сортировки по нескольким полям, советую посмотреть, как работает любая СУБД: от PostgreSQL до, прости господи, MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

#### Для сортировки массива объектов по нескольким полям,

можно использовать вычисляемый "вес" поля, который определяет приоритет различий в одних полях, над различиями в других.

Как мы можем вычислить и применить такой вес в сортировке массива объектов? 
Я считаю наиболее простым вариантом использование такого подхода:

- поля объектов для сортировки определить списком (массивом) - подразумевая, что каждый элемент имеет более высокий приоритет, чем следующий за ним
- соответственно, весом поля считать его порядковый номер с конца списка полей для сортировки
- результат сравнения значений каждого из полей вычислять как
  `Math.sign(cmpResult) * (2 ** ri)`
  , где *cmpResult* - числовой результат компаратора, а *ri* - порядковый номер с конца списка полей
- итоговым результатом сравнения объектов считать как сумму результатов сравнения полей

Таким образом, результат сравнения каждого поля мы сначала "нормализуем"  приводя к одному значению из набора [-1, 0, +1], а затем добавляем к этому значению арифметический вес, чтобы обеспечить вес логический.
На практике это означает, что **результат сравнения каждого следующего поля будет гарантированно меньше по модулю, чем результат сравнения предыдущего** => результаты сравнения полей в общей сумме повлияют на общий итог сравнения соответственно их весу.

---

Демо (ES7+):

```js
function sortArrayOfObjects(arr, rules) {
  if (!arr.length) return arr;
  const defaultComparator = (a, b) => a - b,
        rulesCount = rules.length;
  return arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if ((typeof a !== 'object') || (typeof b !== 'object')) return 0;
    return rules.reduce((sum, { key, comparator = defaultComparator }, i) => {
      const weight = 2 ** (rulesCount - i);
      return sum + Math.sign(comparator(a[key], b[key], a, b)) * weight;
    }, 0);
  });
}

/* Данные */
const arr = [
  { name: "John", age: 24, dept: 'dev' },
  { name: "John", age: 31, dept: 'dev' },
  { name: "John", age: 22, dept: 'qa' },
  { name: "Adam", age: 24, dept: 'qa' },
  { name: "Adam", age: 27, dept: 'dev' },
  { name: "Rose", age: 19, dept: 'sales' },
];

/* Ожидаемый результат при dept(), name(), age(): [
  { dept: "sales", name: "Rose", age: 19 },
  { dept: "qa",    name: "Adam", age: 24 },
  { dept: "qa",    name: "John", age: 22 },
  { dept: "dev",   name: "Adam", age: 27 },
  { dept: "dev",   name: "John", age: 24 },
  { dept: "dev",   name: "John", age: 31 },
] */

/* Тест */
print(sortArrayOfObjects(arr, [
  { key: 'dept', comparator: (b, a) => a.localeCompare(b) },
  { key: 'name', comparator: (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b) },
  { key: 'age' },   // компаратор по-умолчанию (предполагает числовые значения, сортировка по возрастанию)
]));


/* Вспомогательная функция вывода */
function print(arr) {
  console.log(`[\n  ${arr.map(
    v => JSON.stringify(v).replace(/"/g, '\'').replace(/[:,]/g, '$& ')
  ).join(',\n  ')},\n]`);
}
```

В примере сознательно не добавлена обработка возможных ошибок, для того чтобы сделать код понятнее. И, следует упомянуть самые крупные недостатки этого кода, которые ограничивают его применение только демонстрацией в учебных целях:

- Он мееедленный, т.к. в нем выполняются бесполезные вычисления компараторов (решение через `||`-цепочки, в ответе Qwertiy - будет работать быстрее)
- Максимально возможный размер списка полей для сортировки ограничен (52 элементами, если учитывать предел 2<sup>ri</sup> по `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` в тек. версии Chrome для Linux)

---

*Выражаю благодарность участникам **Grundy** и **Qwertiy** за указание на мои ошибки, и дельные замечания к ответу.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126676/discussion-on-answer-by-yar85-----).