# Сортировка числовых ключей разной разрядности, пришедших из базы в строковом виде. Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
angular.module('orderByExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.customers =
          [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', id:"11"},
           {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', id:"19"},
           {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', id:"3"},
           {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', id:"10"},
           {name:'Paul', phone:'355-8765', id:"7"},
           {name:'Stef', phone:'255-8765', id:"9"},
           {name:'Stiii', phone:'855-8765', id:"1"},];
      $scope.predicate = 'id';
      $scope.reverse = false;
      $scope.order = function(predicate) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
      };
    }]);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="orderByExample">
        <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr class="success">
                    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortBy = 'id'; reverse = !reverse">id</a></th>
                    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortBy = 'name'; reverse = !reverse">name</a></th>
                    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortBy = 'phone'; reverse = !reverse">phone</a></th>                       
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
                    <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.phone}}</td>                 
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Когда в этой таблице сортировка происходит по id, то сортируется в таком порядке: 1, 10, 11..., 2, 21... 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

**UPD:** понял, что это происходит потому, что у меня из БД приходят данные в строковом виде: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Razzwan/atvt8qfc/1/). Не могу сообразить, как их в числа преобразовать. Все в этом дело.

Как сделать, чтоб порядок был нормальный?

**UPD2:** в рамках поставленной задачи решить вопрос не удалось. Решил тем, что стал отправлять json объект в правильном формате. Т.е. сразу преобразовал `id` в тип `integer`. И именно в таком виде передал Angular-у. [Реализация на Laravel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462407)

Comment: А где сами данные?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432369/Как-написать-компаратор-для-сортировки

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Это не то, что мне нужно. Нужно понять, как элементы массива на лету преобразовать из строковых переменных в числовые. Сортировка в Angular уже реализована.

Comment: Добавил данные и реализацию кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот работающий пример с сортировкой. Сортирует числа в правильном порядке.

```js
  angular.module('orderByExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.friends =
          [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', id:100},
           {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', id:19},
           {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', id:21},
           {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', id:35},
           {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', id:1}];
      $scope.predicate = 'id';
      $scope.reverse = false;
      $scope.order = function(predicate) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
      };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="orderByExample">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <table class="friend">
    <tr>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="order('id')">ID</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="order('name')">Name</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="order('phone')">Phone Number</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
      <td>{{friend.id}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Еле врубился, как это работает.

Comment: Нифига он не работает. Заменил 21 на 3 - сортировка сломалась.

Comment: @Razzwan, все работает http://jsfiddle.net/atvt8qfc/

Comment: У меня из БД приходят данные в строковом виде: http://jsfiddle.net/Razzwan/atvt8qfc/1/ не могу сообразить, как их в числа преобразовать. В этом дело.

Comment: @Razzwan, почему на сервере не приводите данные к нужному виду? Вот пример на js http://jsfiddle.net/atvt8qfc/2/ , но это извращение :Р