# Как получить json-объект с числовыми значениями из БД средствами Laravel5?

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

*Вопрос является логическим продолжением этого вопроса: ["Сортировка числовых ключей разной разрядности, пришедших из базы в строковом виде. Angular"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462198)*

Как средствами Laravel получить массив json объектов с числовыми значениями?

Дело в том, что метод модели `::all()` *(в прочем, как и другие методы, преобразующие данные в json формат)* автоматически преобразует данные, полученные из БД в json. Но, если в базе данных у меня были поля типа integer, то значения этих полей преобразуются в строки. Вместо ожидаемого: `[{"id":15},{"price":132}...]` я получаю: `[{"id":"15"},{"price":"132"}...]`

Как заставить Laravel возвращать json-объекты с числовыми значениями полей типа integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, для этого в Laravel есть [специальный инструмент](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators). Он способен изменить любое, получаемое из БД поле в необходимый формат. Достаточно только написать в модели следующий код (для моего случая):

```
public function getIdAttribute($value)
{
    return (int)$value;
}
```

И он преобразует необходимый элемент к нужному формату. В моем случае он преобразует все элементы с ключом 'id' к типу integer. В json представлении это исключит кавычки из значения.

Answer (score 1):

Или так, там же в модели:

```
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'integer',
];
```