# Отсортировать JS-массив по числовой части его элементов

Tags: javascript

Есть массив на JavaScript'e, каждый элемент которого содержит одно и то же слово с решеткой, после которого идёт определённое число, потом точка с запятой и какой то текст например:

```
array1 = ["field#1;textA","field#110;textB","field#123;textC","field#2;textD","field#3;textE"];
```

Нужно разделить каждый элемент этого массива на две части, с первой убрать слово с решеткой, чтобы получить само число, это число вместе с текстом обвернуть в хтмл-теги, всунуть в другой массив и отсортировать этот другой массив по "числовой части" его элементов в порядке возрастания числа т.е.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
array1 = ["field#1;textA","field#110;textB","field#123;textC","field#2;textD","field#3;textE"];
array2 = [];
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    var parts = array1[i].split(';');
    var number = parts[0];
    var number = number.substring(6); // убираем field#
    var text = parts[1];
    array2.push('<p><span>'+number+'</span>: '+text+'</p>');
}
for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    console.log(array2[i]);
}
</script>
```

Сейчас я получаю в консоле:

```
<p><span>1</span>: textA</p>
<p><span>110</span>: textB</p>
<p><span>123</span>: textC</p>
<p><span>2</span>: textD</p>
<p><span>3</span>: textE</p>
```

Но нужно отсортировать `array2` по числовой (первой, та что в span'e) части его элементов чтобы получить:

```
<p><span>1</span>: textA</p>
<p><span>2</span>: textD</p>
<p><span>3</span>: textE</p>
<p><span>110</span>: textB</p>
<p><span>123</span>: textC</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
["field#1;textA","field#110;textB","field#123;textC","field#2;textD","field#3;textE"].sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.match(/field#(\d+)/)[1] - b.match(/field#(\d+)/)[1];
})
```

А вообще, почитай: [Как написать компаратор для сортировки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432369/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: @Qwerity, спасибо тебе! Я скорее регулярные выражения писать не умею)