# Сортировка ячейки таблицы с помощью jquery по первой букве в первой ячейке

Tags: javascript, jquery, сортировка

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Обьем
    </td>
    <td>
      175
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Расход
    </td>
    <td>
      3л
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Как можно отсортировать список по первой букве слов *"Обьем"*, *"Расход"* и вывести?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432369 Полезно почитать. Ваше решение где?

Comment: как должно выглаыдеть после сортировки?

Answer (score 0):

Одно из самых простых решений - плагин для jquery (менее 2 кБ)
https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin