# Как отсортировать таблицу по дате?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть таблица (приведена ниже), данные получаются по средствам АПИ и вставляются в таблицу, каждые 20 минут новые данные. Но часто данные получаются в разброс по дате вылета. Как отсортировать по дате вылета данные по средством JS? Спасибо

```html
<table class="table table-hover" style="max-width: 1200px;min-width: 320px;width: 100%;text-align: center;margin: 0px auto;">
    <thead style="background: #eaf9fc;">
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Пункт отправления</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Пункт назначения</th>
        <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Авиакомпания</th> <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Цена, р.</th> <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Дата вылета</th>
<th class="mob" style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Обратная дата</th>
<th> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>    <tbody style="background: #fff0f54d;">
<tr>
<td data-label="Пункт отправления" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Москва&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-label="Пункт назначения" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Санкт-Петербург&nbsp; </td>

     <td data-label="Авиакомпания" class="mob"><img alt="" src="https://pics.avs.io/180/70/N4.png" width="120" height="50"></td>
<td data-label="Цена, р." style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">3096&nbsp;  RUB &nbsp; </td> 
<td data-label="Дата вылета" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-04-24</td>
<td data-label="Обратная дата" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-04-26</td>
      <td class="poisk" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;"><a class="poiski" style="text-decoration: none;" rel="nofollow" role="button" alt="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" title="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" href="/#">Поиск</a></td></tr>
<tr>
<td data-label="Пункт отправления" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Москва&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-label="Пункт назначения" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Санкт-Петербург&nbsp; </td>

     <td data-label="Авиакомпания" class="mob"><img alt="" src="https://pics.avs.io/180/70/FV.png" width="120" height="50"></td>
<td data-label="Цена, р." style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">6323&nbsp;  RUB &nbsp; </td> 
<td data-label="Дата вылета" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-04-24</td>
<td data-label="Обратная дата" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-07-26</td>
      <td class="poisk" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;"><a class="poiski" style="text-decoration: none;" rel="nofollow" role="button" alt="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" title="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" href="/#">Поиск</a></td></tr>
<tr>
<td data-label="Пункт отправления" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Москва&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-label="Пункт назначения" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Санкт-Петербург&nbsp; </td>

     <td data-label="Авиакомпания" class="mob"><img alt="" src="https://pics.avs.io/180/70/D2.png" width="120" height="50"></td>
<td data-label="Цена, р." style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">11685&nbsp;  RUB &nbsp; </td> 
<td data-label="Дата вылета" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-08-15</td>
<td data-label="Обратная дата" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-09-26</td>
      <td class="poisk" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;"><a class="poiski" style="text-decoration: none;" rel="nofollow" role="button" alt="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" title="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" href="/#">Поиск</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как написать компаратор для сортировки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432369/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Сортировать нужно данные после получения, а не разметку.

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю. Данные по АПИ, я их постоянно не знаю. Вот этот код у меня выводит дату вылета  . date("d.m.Y", strtotime($item->departure_at)) .

Comment: У тебя javascript в тегах вопроса, а не php. Зачем мне этот кусок кода на php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function tableSort(table) {
  $('tbody > tr', table).sort(function(a, b) {
    return $('td[data-label="Дата вылета"]', a).text() > $('td[data-label="Дата вылета"]', b).text();
  }).each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo(table);
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('table').each(function() {
    tableSort('table');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover" style="max-width: 1200px;min-width: 320px;width: 100%;text-align: center;margin: 0px auto;">
    <thead style="background: #eaf9fc;">
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Пункт отправления</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Пункт назначения</th>
        <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Авиакомпания</th> <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Цена, р.</th> <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Дата вылета</th>
<th class="mob" style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 20px;">Обратная дата</th>
<th> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>    <tbody style="background: #fff0f54d;">
<tr>
<td data-label="Пункт отправления" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Москва&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-label="Пункт назначения" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Санкт-Петербург&nbsp; </td>

     <td data-label="Авиакомпания" class="mob"><img alt="" src="https://pics.avs.io/180/70/N4.png" width="120" height="50"></td>
<td data-label="Цена, р." style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">3096&nbsp;  RUB &nbsp; </td> 
<td data-label="Дата вылета" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-04-20</td>
<td data-label="Обратная дата" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-04-26</td>
      <td class="poisk" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;"><a class="poiski" style="text-decoration: none;" rel="nofollow" role="button" alt="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" title="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" href="/#">Поиск</a></td></tr>
<tr>
<td data-label="Пункт отправления" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Москва&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-label="Пункт назначения" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Санкт-Петербург&nbsp; </td>

     <td data-label="Авиакомпания" class="mob"><img alt="" src="https://pics.avs.io/180/70/FV.png" width="120" height="50"></td>
<td data-label="Цена, р." style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">6323&nbsp;  RUB &nbsp; </td> 
<td data-label="Дата вылета" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-04-24</td>
<td data-label="Обратная дата" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-07-26</td>
      <td class="poisk" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;"><a class="poiski" style="text-decoration: none;" rel="nofollow" role="button" alt="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" title="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" href="/#">Поиск</a></td></tr>
<tr>
<td data-label="Пункт отправления" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Москва&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-label="Пункт назначения" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">&nbsp; Санкт-Петербург&nbsp; </td>

     <td data-label="Авиакомпания" class="mob"><img alt="" src="https://pics.avs.io/180/70/D2.png" width="120" height="50"></td>
<td data-label="Цена, р." style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">11685&nbsp;  RUB &nbsp; </td> 
<td data-label="Дата вылета" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-04-22</td>
<td data-label="Обратная дата" class="mob" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">2017-09-26</td>
      <td class="poisk" style="font-size: 1.8rem;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;"><a class="poiski" style="text-decoration: none;" rel="nofollow" role="button" alt="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" title="авиабилеты Москва Санкт-Петербург" href="/#">Поиск</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: В вашем примере данные отсортировались с конца в начало, а нужно с начала в конечную дату на увеличение

Comment: @Arcadiy, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое