# Как найти 3 самых длинных слова на js

Tags: javascript

Задача такая: спросить у пользователя текст произвольной длины;
найти во введённом тексте три самых длинных слова. Так вот текст запросил, слова на массив разбил, лишние запятые убрал, даже создал новый массив с длительностями слов. По сути задача: как из массива чисел найти 3 самых больших.

```
var text = prompt('Введите любой произвольный текст', 'Футбол это игра, целью которой является забить мяч в ворота противника');
        var textArr = text.split(' ');
        for (i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
            textArr[i] = textArr[i].replace(',', '');
        };
        var textArrLength = [];
        for (i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
            textArrLength[i] = textArr[i].length;
        };
```

Answer (score 10):

Можно с помощью кастомной функции сортировки масива, отсортировать по длине и взять первые 3 :

```js
var text = 'Футбол это игра, целью которой является забить мяч в ворота противника';
var textArr = text.split(' ');

var newArr = textArr.sort(compare);

console.log('Три самые длинные слова : ' + newArr[0] + ' ' + newArr[1] + ' ' + newArr[2]);

function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.length > b.length) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.length < b.length) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

О сортировке массивов почитать можно [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Спасибо, класс!

Comment: @PolonskiyP незачто, если ответ подошел отметьте галкой слева, чтобы было видно что решен.

Comment: и тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988. Только сортировка ради выбора максимальных элементов - это не очень хорошо. // cc @PolonskiyP