# алгоритм работы метода Array.prototype.sort()

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

> Метод `sort` сортирует имеющийся объект `Array`; нового объекта
>   `Array` не создается.
>
> Если указать функцию в аргументе sortFunction, она должна возвращать
>   одно из следующих значений:
>
> - Отрицательное значение, если первый переданный аргумент меньше    второго аргумента.
> - Нуль, если аргументы эквивалентны.
> - Положительное значение, если первый аргумент больше второго    аргумента.

К примеру есть массив `var arr = [2, 8, 5];`. Если вызвать метод с `0` и `-1` результат будет одинаковым.

```js
var firstArr = [2, 8, 5],
    secondArr = [2, 8, 5];

firstArr.sort(function(){
  return -1;
});

secondArr.sort(function(){
  return 0;
});

console.log(firstArr, secondArr);
```

Какая разница между `-1` и `0`?

**Update**: Какая практическая необходимость в `0` и `-1`, если конечный результат их говорит о том, что сортировка не требуется. Почему просто не сделать `a > b ? 1 : 0`? Приведите пожалуйста практический пример, где отсутствие третьего значения (`0` или `-1`) приведет к ошибке в сортировке, что бы можно было понять их практическую принадлежность в работе метода.

Comment: Ошибки не будет никогда - так уж устроен js. Но и правильной сортировки - тоже.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Какая разница между -1 и 0?

Скорее всего, никакой.

0 говорит, что все элементы равны, а равные элементы могут идти в любом порядке.

-1 делает функцию сравнения некорректной, поскольку любой элемент меньше любого другого, в том числе самого себя, но в js это не приводит к ошибке. Однако, порядок в таком случае никакой не гранатируется.

А вообще, вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988

Comment: _-1 делает функцию сравнения некорректной, поскольку любой элемент меньше любого другого, в том числе самого себя, но в js это не приводит к ошибке. Однако, порядок в таком случае никакой не гранатируется._

Можете пожалуйста переформулировать ваш комментарий. Просто я думал что -1 говорит что положение двух операндов находятся в правильной последовательности.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, -1 говорит, что первый аргумент меньше второго. Никакой правильной последовательности нет, потому что функцию можно вызывать с любыми элементами массива.

Comment: @Qwertit я не правильно выразился. под правильной последовательностью, я хотел сказать, что первый аргумент меньше второго, а значит сортировки не требуется. И вы мне так и не объяснили свой комментарий: _-1 делает функцию сравнения некорректной, поскольку любой элемент меньше любого другого, в том числе самого себя, но в js это не приводит к ошибке. Однако, порядок в таком случае никакой не гранатируется._

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, а кто сказал, что функция должна сравнивать первый элемент со вторым? А если она сравнит второй с первым вместо этого?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70858/discussion-between---and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 0):

Разница между `-1` и `0` - один :).

Возвращая `-1`, Вы говорите, что первый элемент всегда меньше второго. Порядок подачи элементов массива как параметров в функцию `sort` - очевидно соответствует их относительному положению в массиве. Pезультат - сортировка не требуется.

Возвращая ноль, Вы говорите, что все элементы одинаковые - сортировка не требуется.

*Update*

А-а-а, может, Вы пока не понимаете, как правильно писать функции `sort`? У этой функции должно быть два параметра, возвращать значение она должна в зависимости от этих параметров, а вызывается она алгоритмом, когда ему надо сравнить два элемента массива.

```js
var arr1 = [2, 8, 5],
    arr2 = [2, 8, 5];

arr1.sort(function(a, b){
  return a - b;
});
console.log("ascending:", arr1);

arr2.sort(function(a, b){
  return b - a;
});
console.log("descending:", arr2);
```

Comment: существенная правка, однако, я уж почти коммент отправил :D

Comment: Как это влияет на алгоритм, если в результате сортировка не требуется?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Смысл Вашего вопроса от меня ускользает. Сортируете Вы массив, который изначально отсортирован или состоит из одинаковых (с точки зрения функции `sort`) элементов. Все элементы останутся на своих местах.

Comment: @Igor есть массив [1,2,3,4], и я его прогоню через метод `sort` передав аргументом функцию, которая возвращает 0 (return 0;). На массив это не как не повлияет, но по факту это ложь. Какой смысл тогда в -1 и 0, если результат будет одним и тем же?

Comment: Так это Вы лжете в Вашей функции `sort`. Не лжите, и массив будет отсортирован правильно. Я уже написал в ответе, почему результат будет одинаковым.

Comment: @Igor Я лгу намеренно, что бы понять какова необходимость 0 и -1, ибо это ни как не влияет на работу алгоритма. Приведите мне пример, где намеренная фальсификация приведет к ошибки, и тогда будет наглядно видно, что в это есть какой - то практический смысл, а пока для меня это просто формальность.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, сам алгоритм сортировки зависит от реализации. В зависимости от реализации одинаковые элементы могут меняться местами, а могут не меняться. Следовательно, в зависимости от реализации алгоритма при использовании 0 и -1 результаты могут быть разными. Продемонстрировать на практике может быть проблематично, так как для этого нужно точно знать, какой именно из алгоритмов используется в конкретном движке. Хотя в соседнем ответе пример вполне демонстрирует.

Comment: @Grundy то есть существуют случаи, когда проверка на равенство необходима и влияет на алгоритм?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, они вполне могут существовать.

Answer (score 0):

Не все браузеры используют устойчивую сортировку(где необходимое условие как раз что а и b могут оставаться неизменными),поэтому при сравнении следует возвращать ноль.Представьте у Вас два элемента и они равны друг другу,как Вы их сравните?В худшем случае получится петля.Поэтому,чтобы везде работало корректно, стоит делать как описано в спецификации.

Попробуйте в Chrome,при последующих сортировках элемент в центре будет перемещаться.

```js
var firsttime = true;

function dosort() {
  var elements = document.getElementById('test').children;
  var sortMe = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    sortMe.push(elements[i]);
  sortMe.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (firsttime) {
      if (a.innerText < b.innerText) return -1;
      if (a.innerText > b.innerText) return 1;
      else return 0;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
  var parent = document.getElementById('test');
  parent.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0, l = sortMe.length; i < l; i++) {
    parent.appendChild(sortMe[i]);
  }
  firsttime = false;
}
```

```html
<div id=test>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>E</div>
</div>

<input type=button value="Sort" onclick="dosort()">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему при повторной сортировке меняются значения?

Comment: Вообще не понимаю, что показывает этот ответ и в чём смысл приведённого кода...

Comment: @Qwertiy поддерживаю.

Comment: "Почему при повторной сортировке меняются значения?" А теперь попробуйте тоже самое в браузере  Firefox,потом как Вы и хотели закомментируйте строку с -1,посмотрите что получится.

Comment: @Александр это не ответ на мой вопрос.

Comment: @Виталик Черный,Вы уже приняли ответ,поэтому считаю  Вам действительно для ответа надо было написать,что никакой разницы нет.Вам нужен был практический пример,я его указал.Еще раз повторю,алгоритмы сортировки реализованы в разных браузерах по разному,поэтому если Вы сначала бы попробовали в Chrome(где неустойчивый алгоритм сортировки),а потом в Firefox(где устойчивый алгоритм сортировки) увидели бы разницу...

Comment: @Александр ваш ответ очень плохо сформулирован, и не понял, что вы им хотели сказать. исходя из ваших слов и поведения двух браузеров, можно сделать вывод, что один и тот же метод реализован по разному? я правильно вас понял? просто я себе даже не мог представить, что один и тот же метод может работать по разному, ибо должен быть один стандарт. просто я не знаю всех тонкостей.

Comment: @Александр по поводу моего выбора, то я опирался на опыт ответчика, и на его ответ, который он привел в пример и на данный момент я в чате общаюсь с ним, что бы окончательно разобраться. меня интересует только истина.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, _один и тот же метод может работать по разному, ибо должен быть один стандарт_ - в стандарте как раз указано, что метод сортировки `Implementation defined`, то есть реализация может быть в принципе любой, основанной на сравнениях элементов

Comment: Реализация конечно отличается,поэтому в описании метода пишут,что сортировка не обязательна устойчива,зависит от браузера.