# Как отсортировать числа в массиве по ближайшим к числу?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив:

```
[["1.243","red"],["1.242","green"],["1.2425","orange"],
["1.3","grey"],["1.35","grey"],["1.244","grey"]]
```

и число например 1.31

Нужно его отсортировать так, чтоб первые элементы были ближайшие к 1.31 и дальше по убывание близости.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let arr = [["1.243","red"],["1.242","green"],["1.2425","orange"],
["1.3","grey"],["1.35","grey"],["1.244","grey"]];
```

Сортировка:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return Math.abs(Math.abs(a[0])-1.31) - Math.abs(Math.abs(b[0])-1.31);
});
```

Когда-то поднимался вопрос,нужно ли в функции sort возвращать 0 или 1,отвечал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763237/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-array-prototype-sort/763262#763262)

Comment: При использовании отрицательных чисел у вас будет неверная сортировка.

Comment: Я написал сортировку по модулю(что очевидно),для отрицательных чисел достаточно убрать внутри Math.abs

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [
  ["1.243", "red"],
  ["1.242", "green"],
  ["1.2425", "orange"],
  ["1.3", "grey"],
  ["1.35", "grey"],
  ["1.244", "grey"]
];

function sortClosestTo(arr, num, numSelector) {
  arr.sort((l, r) =>
    Math.abs(numSelector(l) - num) - Math.abs(numSelector(r) - num));
}

sortClosestTo(data, 1.31, (el) => +el[0]);

console.log(data);
```

Для отрицательных числах это так же рассчитывается верно:

```js
var data = [
  ["1.243", "red"],
  ["-1.242", "green"],
  ["-1.27", "greens"],
  ["1.2425", "orange"],
  ["1.3", "grey"],
  ["-1.35", "grey"],
  ["1.244", "grey"]
];

function sortClosestTo(arr, num, numSelector) {
  arr.sort((l, r) =>
    Math.abs(numSelector(l) - num) - Math.abs(numSelector(r) - num));
}

sortClosestTo(data, -1.31, (el) => +el[0]);

console.log(data);
```