# Сравнение массивов в js

Tags: javascript

```
console.log([2,6,10]>[2,10,0]);
```

Вернет `true`, почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что сравниваются их строковые представления:

```js
console.log(
  [2, 6, 10].toString(), 
  [2, 10, 0].toString(), 
  [2, 6, 10] > [2, 10, 0]
);
```

> А почему тогда `[1,1,1]` не идентичен и не равен `[1,1,1]`?

Почему не равен? Равен:

```js
var a = [1,1,1];
var b = [1,1,1];

console.log(!(a > b) && !(a < b));
```

---

> А как правильно их сравнить тогда?

Поэлементно.

Comment: А как правильно их сравнить тогда?

Comment: @KopkanСначала надо определить, что значит: "один массив больше/меньше другого". Но я уже догадываюсь.

Comment: А почему тогда `[1,1,1]` не идентичен и не равен  `[1,1,1]` ?

Comment: @doox911 Добавил в ответ.

Comment: А вот так `console.log([0,0,0]===[0,0,0]);
VM1467:1 false` - консоль **chrome**

Comment: @doox911 Потому что операторы `==`/`===` работают по-другому.

Comment: Я это понимаю, но и так и так не равны.

Comment: @doox911 Что есть "и так и так не равны"?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90696/discussion-between-doox911-and-igor).

Answer (score 2):

При сравнении на > и < объекты приводятся к примитивам - в случае массивов это строки, в которых перечислены все элементы массива через запятую. Поэтому `[2,6,10]>[2,10,0]` - это то же самое, что `"2,6,10">"2,10,0"`, а строки сравниваются лексикографически. Первые 2 символа `2,` здесь совпадают, а вот дальше сравнивается `6` и `1` - очевидно, что первое больше - вот и получается true.

Если требуется сравнить массивы поэлементно, надо написать собственную функцию, которая сравнивает их в цикле.

PS: Немного не по теме, [но может пригодиться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988).

Comment: Насчет вашего комментария к моему удаленному ответу. Приводятся. Приводятся к логич. типу, обрабатываются, и возвращается один из операндов (уже в том виде, в котором он был передан).

Answer (score -2):

Данная функция вернет номер (начиная с 1) большего массива и 0 если они равны

```js
function compareArrays(m1, m2)
{
for(let i=0; i<m1.length && i<m2.length; i++)
{
   if(m1[i]>m2[i]){ return 1; }
   if(m1[i]<m2[i]){ return 2; }
}
if(m1.length>m2.length){return 1;}
if(m1.length<m2.length){return 2;}
if(m1.length==m2.length){return 0;}

return false;
}

console.log(compareArrays([5,6,4], [5,10,0]));
```

Comment: @meine, вообще-то он его писал...

Comment: @Qwertiy, неловко получилось)