# Сортировка у меня правильно сделана?

Tags: javascript

```js
var users = [{
  name: "Вася",
  surname: 'Иванов',
  age: 20
}, {
  name: "Петя",
  surname: 'Чапаев',
  age: 25
}, {
  name: "Маша",
  surname: 'Медведева',
  age: 18
}];

// по полю name (Вася, Маша, Петя)
users.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;
});

// по полю age  (Маша, Вася, Петя)
users.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.age > b.age ? 1 : -1;
});

//Я решил вот так 

function byField(a){
  return function(){
    return users.a > users.a ? 1 : -1
  }
  
}

users.sort(byField('name'));

users.forEach(function(user) {
  console.log( user.name);
});


users.sort(byField('age'));

users.forEach(function(user) {
  console.log( user.name);
});

//А у автора вот так 
function byField(field) {
    return function(a, b) {
      return a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1;
    }
  }

// Получается у меня ошибка ?
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, **конкретную проблему или ошибку** и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> return users.a > users.a ? 1 : -1
> ```

Неправильно. Обращение к полю из переменной делается не через точку.

---

А вообще про сортировку вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988.

Comment: чтобы правильно было надо методу sort передать функцию где будет 2 аргумента ?

Comment: Можно использовать filter вместо sort ?