# метод sort() в JS

Tags: javascript

Почему на консоль выводится

```
'3 7'
'13 3'
'5 13'
```

a не

```
'7 3'
'3 13'
'13 5'
```

?

заранее спасибо

```js
var arr = [7, 3, 13, 5, 134, 8, 1];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b);
});
```

Comment: Ты передал в sort функцию которая ничего не возвращает. В результате ты получишь что угодно и вряд ли это будет отсортированный массив.

Comment: Ну и что и в каком порядке sort будет передавать в функцию сравнения нигде не регламентировано. Если очень хочется знать точно, придётся читать исходники соответствующего движка JS.

Comment: Про что угодно я пожалуй неправ. Вроде все движки реализуют стабильную сортировку, так что на выходе должен получится тот же массив.

Comment: @Drakonoved Это совершенно неважно. Код сортировки вызывает нашу функцию, чтобы сравнить два числа, и все.

Comment: @Drakonoved https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort . Если a > b должна вернуть эта функция `+1`. Массив будет отсортирован по возрастанию.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вы написали как sort сравнивает числа
2. Вы должны передать функцию и способ сравнения например
3. В массиве метод sort() сортирует на месте
4. Вот тут [Как написать компаратор для сортировки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432369/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8/432370#432370) больше найдете информации про сортировку ...

```js
var arr = [7, 3, 13, 5, 134, 8, 1];
arr.sort( (a, b) => {
  if( a > b) return 1;
  if( a < b) return -1;
  if( a == b) return 0
})
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Которое можно сократить до `arr.sort( (a, b) => a - b );` )

Comment: @Drakonoved а можете придумать такую ситуацию?) Всегда же будет одно из трех... Даже если `a` или `b` окажутся не числами. Вместо последнего `if( a == b) return 0` можно было написать просто `return 0` ... Если не выполнятся условия `a > b` или `a < b` — чтобы уж точно вернуть 0.

Comment: Автор вопроса по факту спрашивает: почему аргумент `a` равен трем, а не семи. То есть его интересует для чего переменные меняют местами.

Comment: ) перечитайте вопрос и постарайтесь понять разницу между *Как* и *Почему*. Почему `a=3` и `b=7`, хотя в изначальном массиве `[7, 3, ...]`