# Как отсортировать обьект в JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть обьект :

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "300A"

    },
 {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "400"

    },

 {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "400b"

    },

{
        "id": "4",
        "name": "200"

    }]
```

Нужно отсортировать по имени, по цифрам,т.е.

```
200,300,300А,400,400b
```

Comment: Вообще-то это массив.

Answer (score 2):

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988

```js
console.log([
  { "id": "1",   "name": "300A" },
  { "id": "2",   "name": "400"  },
  { "id": "3",   "name": "400b" },
  { "id": "4",   "name": "200"  },
].sort(
  (x, y) => parseInt(x.name) - parseInt(y.name) || (x.name > y.name) - (x.name < y.name)
))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = [
  { "id": "1", "name": "300A" },
  { "id": "2", "name": "400" },
  { "id": "3", "name": "400b" },
  { "id": "4", "name": "200" },
  { "id": "5", "name": "400a" }
];

a.sort((a, b) => {
  var res = parseInt(a.name) - parseInt(b.name);
  if (res == 0 && a.name != b.name) {
    res = (a.name < b.name)? -1 : 1;
  }
  return res;
});
console.log(a);
```