# JS сортировка массива [1.1,1.10,1.11,1.2...]

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста отсортировать массив вида [1.1, 1.10, 1.11, 1.12, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, ...] так, чтобы чтобы элементы шли по возрастанию как до точки, так и после.

Надо: [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.10, 1.11, 1.12, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, ...]

Пробовал делать parseFloat() в функции sort(), но 1.11 < 1.2  и это не сработало

Comment: в массиве хранятся строки?

Comment: @Grundy, их можно и на числах вызывать, только почти бессмысленно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, в числах ты не сможешь различить `1.1` и `1.10`, а в строках сможешь

Comment: @Grundy, я сначала вопрос неправильно прочитал.

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать так.

1. Превращаем число в строку,
2. разбиваем по точке, получаем два числа, до и после точки.
3. Сравниваем сначала числа до точки.
4. Если они равны, сравниваем числа после точки.

```js
const array = [1.1, 1.10, 1.11, 1.12, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3];

array.sort((a, b) => {
  const [a1, a2] = String(a).split('.').map(Number);
  const [b1, b2] = String(b).split('.').map(Number);

  if (a1 > b1) return 1;
  if (a1 < b1) return -1;
  if (a2 > b2) return 1;
  if (a2 < b2) return -1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(array);
```

Но, как вы видите, есть подвох: два раза повторяется `1.1`, потому что число `1.10` превратится в `1.1`. Если вы пытаетесь работать с чем-то вроде индексов вложенных списков, лучше сразу превратить числа в строки, чтобы ноль после дробной части не отбрасывался.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, надо в массиве иметь строки, а не числа. Ну а дальше расписано [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988). В итоге получится так:

```js
var a = ['1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4', '1.10', '1.11', '1.12', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3', '3.1', '3.2', '3.3']

a.sort((x, y) => {
  x = x.split(".")
  y = y.split(".")
  return x[0] - y[0] || x[1] - y[1]
})

console.log(a.join(" "))
```

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, да, именно. Исправил.

Answer (score 0):

сорт который вам может подойти.

Идея сортировки простая

1. Если целые части равны  `(a|0) - (b|0) === 0` (использование бинарных операций для округления чисел)
2. То сравнить дробные части `(""+a).split('.')[1]` (преобразование в сроку, разбивка по точке и взятие дробной части)
3. иначе просто сравнить

```js
const array = [1.1, 1.10, 1.11, 1.12, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2 , 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3];

array.sort((a,b)=> (a|0) - (b|0) === 0 ? +((""+a).split('.')[1]) - +((""+b).split('.')[1]) : a - b) ;


console.log(array);
```

Comment: что за минус непонятно?

Comment: В задании 1.2 должно идти раньше, чем 1.11 и т.п.

Comment: Кажется, нужно добавить return и исправить порядок операторов: `((a|0)-(b|0))` — иначе вычитание будет выполнено перед `|`.

Comment: Подправил ответ

Comment: Вернул в состояние в которое решение задумывалось

Comment: @Grundy Добавил пояснений в ответ

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать так (на лучшее решение не претендую):

```
array.sort((a, b) => a.toString().localeCompare(b.toString())))
```

Comment: К сожалению, при такой сортировке `1.11` будет перед `1.2`.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, нужно добавить [{numeric: true}](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator#Parameters) третьим параметром

Comment: Только `localeCompare` - очень медленная функция, особенно если дойдёт до IE. У меня был случай, когда её использование замедляло сортировку с секунды до 2-5 минут в IE и до 20-60 секунд в хроме.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const array = [1.1, '1.10', 1.11, 1.12, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3];
const sorted = array
               .map(v=>([]+v).split('.'))
               .sort(([a1,a2],[b1,b2])=>Math.sign(a1-b1)||Math.sign(a2-b2))
               .map(v=>v.join('.'));
console.log(sorted);
```