# Как отсортировать массив объектов в js

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно отсортировать массив объектов в js по массиву имен свойств, который передается в функцию. Вот к примеру

```
function sorting(obj, propName){

}


initial = [
    {a : 1, b : "abc"},
    {a : 2, b : "def"},
]

sorting(initial, ["a"]);       //1
sorting(initial, ["b", "a"]);  //2
```

В первом случае объекты в массиве initial должны быть отсортированы по свойству 'a', а во втором первично по свойству 'b' и вторично по свойству 'a'(т.е лексеграфически). Сортировка должна идти по возрастанию и быть устойчивой. Как это сдедлать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как написать компаратор для сортировки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432369/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: @nörbörnën, там сортировки по массиву свойств нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно написать компаратор, которые сперва сравнивает два объекта по нулевому свойству из массива `propName`, если данное свойство одинаково у двух объектов, то по следующему свойству из массива `propName`, и т.д.

Так как спецификация языка не требует, чтобы метод `sort` использовал устойчивую сортировку (*1*), то необходимо самостоятельно позаботиться об обеспечении устойчивости сортировки. Например, можно сортировать не исходный массив, а массив пар `[элемент_исходного_массива, индекс_в_исходном_массиве]`. Если два объекта равны по всем интересующим нас свойствам, то сравниваем индексы объектов.

```js
function sorting(objArr, propName)
{
    for (let i = 0; i < objArr.length; ++i)
        objArr[i] = [objArr[i], i];
    
    function comparator(a, b)
    {
        for (let prop of propName)
        {
            if (a[0][prop] < b[0][prop])
                return -1;
            else if (a[0][prop] > b[0][prop])
                return 1;
        }
        return a[1] - b[1];
    }

    objArr.sort(comparator);

    for (let i = 0; i < objArr.length; ++i)
        objArr[i] = objArr[i][0];
}

let initial = [
    {a : 2, b : "def", c: 7},
    {a : 3, b : "def", c: 6},
    {a : 1, b : "def", c: 5},
    {a : 1, b : "def", c: 4},
    
    {a : 3, b : "abc", c: 3},
    {a : 2, b : "abe", c: 2},
    {a : 2, b : "abd", c: 1},
    {a : 2, b : "abc", c: 0},
];

console.log(1);
sorting(initial, ["a"]);       //1
for (let obj of initial)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

console.log(2);
sorting(initial, ["b", "a"]);  //2
for (let obj of initial)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

---

(*1*):

В *ECMA-262, 9th edition, June 2018* говорится следующее ([Array.prototype.sort](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort)):

> The elements of this array are sorted. The sort is not necessarily stable (that is, elements that compare equal do not necessarily remain in their original order).

Но начиная с *ECMA-262, 10th edition, June 2019* сортировка должна быть стабильной ([Array.prototype.sort](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort)):

> The elements of this array are sorted. The sort must be stable (that is, elements that compare equal must remain in their original order).