# Сортировка таблицы по двум столбцам при загрузке страницы vanilla js

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно, чтобы моя таблица автоматически отсортировалась по двум столбцам ( Name, Available) при загрузке

Я пытаюсь отсортировать следующим образом, но получаю ошибку: `condition is always true since types 'this' and 'number' have no overlap`  в строке `const sortedRows=sortedRowsByName !== 0 ? sortedRowsByName : sortedRowsByAvailable`.

Что я делаю не так?

```js
const table = document.querySelector('.table_sort');
const indexToSorting = [...table.tHead.rows[0].cells].findIndex(cell => cell.classList.contains('sorted-asc'));
const availableIndexes = [...table.tHead.rows[0].cells].findIndex(cell => cell.classList.contains('available'));
const sortedRowsByName = [...table.tBodies[0].rows].sort((rowA, rowB) => {
  const cellA = rowA.cells[indexToSorting].innerText;
  const cellB = rowB.cells[indexToSorting].innerText;
  const nameComparison = cellA.localeCompare(cellB);
  return nameComparison;
});
const sortedRowsByAvailable = [...table.tBodies[0].rows].sort((rowC, rowD) => {
  const cellC = rowC.cells[availableIndexes].innerText;
  const cellD = rowD.cells[availableIndexes].innerText;
  const availableComparison = cellC.localeCompare(cellD);
  return availableComparison;
});
const sortedRows = sortedRowsByName !== 0 ? sortedRowsByName : sortedRowsByAvailable
table.tBodies[0].append(...sortedRows);
```

```html
<table class="table_sort">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sorted-asc">Name</th>
      <th>Genre</th>
      <th>Publish year</th>
      <th>Quanity</th>
      <th class="available">Available</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>name1</td>

      <td>genre1</td>

      <td>year1</td>
      <td>quantity1</td>
      <td>available1</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Может лучше получать просто данные (например, JSON), потом сортировать их с помощью .sort, а потом уже формировать таблицу? Иначе зачем вначале выводить лишний html, который видеть не должны?

Comment: мои данные с сервера поступают сразу на jsp страницу и выводятся

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988

Answer (score 0):

Строчек в таблице мало, у меня с тремя строчками все работает...

```
    <table class="table_sort">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sorted-asc">Name</th>
      <th>Genre</th>
      <th>Publish year</th>
      <th>Quanity</th>
      <th class="available">Available</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>name1</td>

      <td>genre1</td>

      <td>year1</td>
      <td>quantity1</td>
      <td>available12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>aname1</td>

      <td>genre1</td>

      <td>year1</td>
      <td>quantity1</td>
      <td>available11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bname1</td>

      <td>genre1</td>

      <td>year1</td>
      <td>quantity1</td>
      <td>available11</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```